# How to stop a BackgroundWorker externally

Tags: c#, oop, backgroundworker, networkcomms.net

I have a `BackgroundWorker_DoWork` method in my client application which sends a tcp message using NetworkComms.Net to a server and check for an answer.

The method for that last part is
`NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler`
where I can verify if the answer has a certain type and if yes, invoke another method to handle the answer message itself.

What I want to do is to stop the BackgroundWorker from within the handler, but I can't figure out how. Any help is greatly appreciated, as I'm very new to Object-Oriented Programming and I'm probably missing something fundamental.

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    if (backgroundWorker2.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }

    string serverIP = entr_serverIP.Text;

    int serverPORT;
    int.TryParse(entr_serverPORT.Text, out serverPORT);
    bool loop = true;

    while (loop == true)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker2.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            NetworkComms.SendObject("Message", serverIP, serverPORT, "status");

            NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<string>("ReturnHere", DoSomething2);


        }
        catch(DPSBase.CommsException ex2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex2.ToString());

            e.Cancel = true;
            return;

        }


        Thread.Sleep(100);

    }

}


private static void DoSomething2(PacketHeader header, Connection connection, string message)
{
    bool svAlarmSent = false;
    while (svAlarmSent == false)
    {
        if (message == "KEYWORD")
        {
            string svInfo = connection.ConnectionInfo.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

            Form4 form4 = new Form4("KEYWORD", null, svInfo);
            form4.Show();
            svAlarmSent = true;


            backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
            loop = false;


        }

    }

}
```

The two last lines of the above code don't work because the `CancelAsync` method and the `loop` variable don't exist in that context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step to fixing this is to enable cancellation from the `DoSomething2` method.  To do this it needs access to the `backgroundWorker2` variable.  This is a field (attribute), hence you can give it access by making the method non-static:

```
private void DoSomething2(PacketHeader header, Connection connection, string message)
```

The next step is to simple remove the access of the `loop` value from `DoSomething2`.  The responsibility of this method is to signal the cancellation only.  It is the job of the `backgroundWorker2_DoWork` method to respond to this cancellation.

In fact the `loop` variable doesn't even need to be set.  Once `CancelAsync` is called the following conditional will be met:

```
if (backgroundWorker2.CancellationPending)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    return;
}
```

By virtue of returning this code will break the `while` loop by itself.

Overall I would say that this isn't really the intended use of a `BackgroundWorker` though.  Cancellation is supposed to be used to allow the user, or some operation, to signal that the background task should cancel the work and return without completing (if possible).  In this case you are using cancellation to signal the succesful completion of the code.  This works but is somewhat of an unintended use case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking, but here is an easy example how to handle background workers.

```
    private readonly bool _shouldStop;

    public void Start()
    {
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        workerThread.IsBackground = true;
        workerThread.Start();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {            
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {

            //work
        }
    }
    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
    }
```

to start the worker just call Start() and to stop it call RequestStop() 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: This question is specifically about the `BackgroundWorker` type